# Apache POI : Why data is not properly inserted?

Tags: java, excel, apache, for-loop, apache-poi

I want to insert a string to a Matrix of Cells in Excel, Using Apache POI, Here is the code :

```
for (int j=0;j<13;j++){
     for(int i=6;i<30;i++)
     {
        XSSFRow row=sheet6.createRow(i);
        cell0=row.createCell(j);
        cell0.setCellValue("SampleRules_CI_01");
    }
}
```

After executing my program, I get the column j=12 correctly filled, but the other columns (from 0 to 11) are still empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the row each time you get back around to the same value of `i`, when you call the [`createRow` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow%28int%29).  This has the effect of erasing whatever was on that row already, and only the last column doesn't get erased this way.

First, inside your `i` `for` loop, call [the `getRow` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow%28int%29) to see if it already exists.  If it returns `null`, then the row doesn't exist yet and then you can call `createRow`.

```
XSSFRow row = sheet6.getRow(i);
if (row == null)
{
    row = sheet6.createRow(i);
}
```